# Объект движется вперед при нажатии S и наоборот при нажатии W

Tags: unity3d

Есть объект (овца), недавно начал изучать углы Эйлера и все дела (буду благодарен если дадите ресурсы для изучения, такие как книги по юнити), так вот, овца идет вперед по нажатию клавиши S и назад при нажатии клавиши W. Я так понимаю дело именно в осях, а точнее в направлении векторов. Суть такова, что овца должна двигаться вперед/назад и влево/вправо.

Вот код управления овцой

```
    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public float gravity = -9.8f;
    public CharacterController _charController;

    private void Start()
    {
        _charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        Debug.Log(_charController);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        float deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        transform.Translate(-deltaX * Time.deltaTime, 0, deltaZ * Time.deltaTime);
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(deltaX, 0, deltaZ);
        movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, speed);
        movement.y = gravity;
        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
        _charController.Move(movement);
    };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

 в Vector3, где deltaX, я так думаю, надо сделать так, чтобы выражение было именно разностью, т.к у меня получается объект движется в обратную сторону. 
 *объяснил, блин*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст поста не содержит прямого вопроса или описания проблемы, а предложения логически слабо связаны. Причём тут углы эйлера... их тут нет и вообще они отвечают за поворот в 3d пространстве и не связаны с вектором. И это не бином ньютона что бы читать о этом целые книги, банальные углы от 0 до 360 как на обычном круге на школьной доске, только по своему кругу для x, y и z.

Описан лишь желаемый результат после слов: "Суть такова". Вот код:

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
// если компонент обязателен то указываем это
[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]

public class SheepController : MonoBehaviour {
    // для того, чтобы не делать публичным то, что не должно им быть
    // но должно отображаться в инспекторе
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 6.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float _gravity = 9.8f;
    private Transform _transform;
    private CharacterController _controller;
    
    private void Awake () {
        _transform = transform;
        _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update () {
        // вертикаль v на вектор, куда направлен объект, а горизонталь h на вектор с право от него.
        Vector3 Move = _transform.forward*Input.GetAxis("Vertical")+_transform.right*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        // поскольку одновременно зажатые v и h могут дать (1, 1) 
        // и превысить длину в 1 в этом случае его нужно нормализовать
        if (Move.magnitude > 1)
            Move.Normalize();
        Move *= _speed;
        // гравитацию добавляем после наложения на оси объекта, а не до!
        // иначе упав на бок, овца полетит куда направлен живот, а не в низ
        Move.y -= _gravity;
        Move *= Time.deltaTime;
        _controller.Move(Move);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, код работает. Где можно подробнее прочитать про перемещение в Unity? Мало опыта, для меня эта овца, как победа в ВОВ, очень нуждаюсь в ресурсах по юньке.

Comment: Много инструметов перемещения, смотря что и как перемещать, для персонажей `CharacterController`, для другого `Rigidbody`, для третьего вообще `Transform` и каждый целая большая тема. Волшебной таблетки нет. Лучший навык это учиться правильно формулировать запрос google, причём зачастую на eng. Смотреть на найденные примеры и постоянно читать документацию юнити по конкретным классам и их методам если они не понятным, не знакомы или посмотреть на весь фунционал этого класса. Так-же в доках описание и часто есть примеры кода.

Comment: Бедный гугл, мало того, что ему нужно понять, что такое «косается», так ещё и то, что это не про касания, а про коллизии..

Comment: Да, хрень, на "сталкивается", ситуация получше, а на "коллизия" (не ожидал, что в русском используется) оч хорошо. А с "touches" тоже будет задачник.